# How do I properly secure a REST-like service using Spring Security based on cookies?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, cookies, spring-security, session-cookies

I read this article on using Spring Security to "secure" (password-protect) a REST-like service: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/.

This solution is what I seem to want, however, I noticed that at the bottom of the article, the authentication process is based on a cookie. If you notice, after a user logs in, a cookie is sent back to the user, and the user keeps using this cookie on subsequent request to access the REST endpoints (see the curl commands).

My concern about this approach centers on security; meaning, what's to stop the user from sending this cookie to someone else for use or someone from copying this cookie and using the REST service without proper authentication?

Is there a way to set the cookie (or cookies) such that it is valid for only one user? For example, for only the IP that authenticated correctly? But even this is problematic, as multiple users may share one external IP address.

Comment: that depends on what information you put into the cookie (encrypted, hashed etc.) and how you validate. However the approach with cookies is used in multiple situations so not sure why you now have a concern (the same goes for the session id cookies in regular website).

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the general question is, if this problem exists in general, how have others taken additional measures to address these concerns? I suppose I need to research a little bit more into these types of cookie-based authentication approaches, especially their weaknesses, and if anyone has links to educate oneself on, that would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code is just demonstrating how to maintain a session between requests, exactly as your browser would do, by storing the JSESSIONID cookie. So I think your question is really the same as "what's to stop a user from copying the session cookie from their browser and giving it to someone else?". Of course there is nothing to stop them doing that but why would they want to?  The same argument applies to any kind of security token. There's nothing to stop them giving away their username and password either which would have the same effect.

In most cases a web service would be stateless, so it wouldn't use session cookies. But OAuth tokens and so on are just as sensitive, often more so since they usually have a longer life span.

Comment: The REST service, in my case, gives access to digital content. If someone really wanted to, they can give access to any resource by simply supplying the cookie (you can see how easily this can be done with the article's example of using curl).

Comment: How is that any different from simply supplying the username and password so someone else can just type them in? Authentication usually requires the use of some secret information only you have. If it's exchanged for an opaque short-lived cookie as part of the protocol that doesn't make it any more or less secure. Short of adding biometrics or OTP generators to the mix there's not much you can do about it. Even then there would still usually be a session involved for most systems which require a user to log in.

Comment: Imagine if I don't have to supply a u/p credential, but I can just send a cookie file, for someone to gain access? That's the difference. The end result is the same, of course.